# Simplest way to login by BotPasswords and get HTML page-contents

Tags: mediawiki-api

I need to use `wget` or `curl` by terminal... And ideally in one step. My Wiki need standard login (default **Mediawiki v1.33** installation), and I used the page `Especial:BotPasswords` to create

```
 myUserName@myBotName = etc123etc
```

So, **how to use this credentials to get contents by API?**

It is not working,

```
  wget "http://etc.etc123.com/api.php?action=parse&page=MyPage&prop=text&formatversion=2&format=json"
```